# How to get url in symfony using url_for() helper , for the route with a path parameter like ...../:param

Tags: php, symfony1

I couldn't get it to work on symfony  1.4.5
I have a route :

```
edit_page:
  url: /editpages/:page
  param: { module: pages, action: edit }
```

and I want to get to url with a url_for() helper.

```
 <a class="float-right rounded-btn" href="<?php echo url_for('@edit_page'); ?>">Configure</a>
```

this one just is giving me and :

> The "/editpages/:page" route has some
>   missing mandatory parameters (:page).

Answer (score 6):

When error message tells that "route has some missing mandatory parameters", it is a clear sign that you have to add missing mandatory parameters to the route. :)

```
url_for('@edit_page?page=configure');
```